# Jquery Datatables : How to get row.data when click the the button in one column?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

[![enter image description here][1]][1]i have a nested table , I want to having button to generate the row data to info.php by post method (looks like info.php?user = data[0] & key2 = data[2](https://jsfiddle.net/andrewarnier/udgp3x9o/2/)) in one column for each row , 
I have one button but I need one button and perform some MySql when they are clicked to get the row data .
 when click the button will get to every columns data in the row and post these data to info.php and view in popup window,

How can I perform post the row data in the nested datatable to other php  using the button?

[my code](https://jsfiddle.net/andrewarnier/udgp3x9o/2/)

click the button ,cannot get the row data ?

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
     var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
     var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
      alert("References is "+ data[0] +"and section is "+ data[ 1 ]+ " and Stature Titles is "+data[2] );
} );
```

Comment: yeah. if you could post your html and what your have tried so far, that would be great :)

Comment: i have add part of my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-UPDATED
just add class for button class='button-info'

```
 columns:[ 
   { data:'name' },
   { data:'position' }, 
   { data:'salary' },
   {
      "targets": -1,
       "data": null,
      "defaultContent": "<button class='button-info'>Click Me!</button>"
   }
 ]
```

first assign index value for every parent row

```
$("table tbody tr").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('index', index);
})
```

then add new event for click event of that button and get the parent tr index
   just get the index of your selected parent row using data attribute "index" added above

```
 var parent = $(this).closest('table').parents('tr').index();
 var parentIndex = $('tbody tr:nth-child('+(parent)+')').attr('index');
```

and to get your current row in nested data

```
var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
```

so this is the final

```
$('table').on( 'click', 'td .button-info', function () {
    var parent = $(this).closest('table').parents('tr').index();
    var parentIndex = $('tbody tr:nth-child('+(parent)+')').attr('index');
    var currentIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    var data = sections[parentIndex][currentIndex];
    console.log(data);
    return;
    window.open("/info.php?name=" + data.name + "&sal=" + data.salary);
} );
```

See this updated [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/udgp3x9o/13/)

Comment: hi Newbee Dev, from your code ,it's get the parent data not nested datatable data, I want to get nested datatable data not parent data , I have update my code ,but still cannot work ,can you help me how to fix ?

Comment: ah okay. my mistake

Comment: @user6556472 it's okay now check it

Comment: yes, alert data is that I wnat , but how to post these data to popup  info.php like info.php?name = data.name & sal = data.salary when click the button ?

Comment: @user6556472 you want to redirect to that page?

Comment: I want to popup a new window  . And need passing  the row data   to the new popup window in order to access database.

Comment: @user6556472 I updated it now it now open new window check the jsfiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126565/discussion-between-user6556472-and-newbee-dev).

Comment: I have tried you code, but I can click button in the same nested table ,but other nested table button cannot work

Comment: @user6556472 dude I tested it. it works.
https://jsfiddle.net/udgp3x9o/14/   look at that jsfiddle

Comment: It's looks like works. because my nested data is from other php , is it possible to  use   data: <?php echo json_encode($nestedary, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>  instead of data: sections[row.index()] ??

Comment: @user6556472 no dude because you are now looping inside javascript

Comment: I found when I using data: <?php echo json_encode($nestedary, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?> , will get wrong row data ,

Comment: @user6556472 why do you want to use a php inside javascript anyway?

Comment: when i set ordering: true, in nested table ,will get wrong row data

Comment: @user6556472 ah I see

Comment: @user6556472 dude I try it reorder and it still works

Comment: ,I have follow your code https://jsfiddle.net/udgp3x9o/14/   but  the button cannot action ,and  got the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined(…) when press F12

Comment: @user6556472 see me the screen shot

Comment: i have add the screen shot to my question

Comment: it's my fault , I am forgot to add   $("table tbody tr").each(function(index) {
     $(this).attr('index', index);
    })

Comment: @user6556472 So its now working fine? Dont forget to upvote and mark check my answer

Comment: I cannot get the nested row data correctly, it's will get the other row in the same nested table

Comment: can you   move this discussion to chat?

Comment: @user6556472 dude enter the chat now